# This riddle is for everyone*

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> In the darkest of ancient India,
>
> I will take the light out of your day,
>
> the number one Type'O you may say.
>
> From caves to comic books, you make my mark,
>
> I am often associated with the dark.
>
> Enjoy my benefits after a feast,
>
> switch one word and you're a criminal to say the least.
>
> Adorn me when you're mourning,
>
> Pirates may use me as a warning.

**What am I?**

> *Except Anish Kapoor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> The color black?

In the darkest of ancient India,

> Referring to Indian Ink (thanks [MMAdams](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53109/this-riddle-is-for-everyone/53110?noredirect=1#comment163032_53110))

I will take the light out of your day,

> Darkness/black, absence of light

the number one Type'O you may say.

> referring to Type O Negatives "Black No. 1"

From caves to comic books, you make my mark,

> Caves are dark, and comic books use black ink

I am often associated with the dark.

> Black is the color of darkness

Enjoy my benefits after a feast,

> Black Friday, after Thanksgiving ([MMAdams](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53109/this-riddle-is-for-everyone/53110?noredirect=1#comment163033_53110))

switch one word and you're a criminal to say the least.

> **Black Market** - Where criminals go to buy things ;)

Adorn me when you're mourning,

> Wearing black at funerals

Pirates may use me as a warning.

> Pirates have a black flag on their ships and that warns people that they're pirates.

Hint:

> Anish Kapoor was banned from using the pinkest pink color since he got exclusive rights to the blackest black color

Comment: The answer is correct, but you haven't solved all the clues. India, Feast and Pirates (that is so close I would accept it) are incorrect but good guesses :)

Comment: I think the India line is probably referring to India Ink, which in more 'ancient' times was probably more common but is still used by some artists today.

Comment: also, I'm guessing the after a feast line is about Black Friday, the day after Thanksgiving

Comment: @MMAdams is on the ball!

Comment: The Feast answer is a clue to the criminal clue.

Comment: The "criminal" might be infamous outlaw Black Bart?

Comment: HINT: The 'Criminal' hints answer follows on from the 'Feast' answer, it even has the same *theme* "switch one word" ;)

Comment: "Blackout" after a feast, and "Blackmail" as a criminal?

Comment: Is it? I guessed it was the fact that [the answer] was slimming- i.e. once you're stuffed after a feast you would look better in it. But that, ofc, is just one word, so there's nothing left if you chnage it...

Comment: pirates, aledgedly, used "black marks" to signify a lack of considence in their officers (but not yet enough to mutiny.)

Comment: @mr23ceec That was close to my intended answer (mine was made famous by Treasure Island) but the answer given works enough for me.

Comment: @PhilipSchiff The answer for the Feast clue already answered is correct. I feel maybe the criminal one is too hard or relying on what I may have thought general knowledge.